# Java Multiplying 2 integers from strings

Tags: java, string, integer, multiplication

I've tried searching a number of threads in terms of multiplying 2 strings. However, it seems that most of the links I found weren't applicable or I couldn't interpret them well enough.

Would it be possible if could tell me what is wrong with my current code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sample = value1();
    String sample2 = value2();
            //========== Test if users placed any characters within the boxes =========\\
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(sample);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("System detects that you are using characters");
                return;
            }
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(sample2);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("System detects that you are using characters");
                return;
            }
     Integer.parseInt(sample); 
     Integer.parseInt(sample2);
    System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is "+sample * sample2+ ".");
}

public static String value1() { //obtain first user input. 

    String sample = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert Value", "Enter amount ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (sample.isEmpty()) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!", "No Value Detected", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        sample = value1();


    }
    return sample;

}

public static String value2() { //obtain second user input. 

    String sample2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert Value", "Enter amount ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (sample2.isEmpty()) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!", "No Value Detected", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        sample2 = value2();


    }
    return sample2;

}
```

}

My final output should multiply the following numbers

`System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is "+sample * sample2+ ".");`

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to multiply *integers*, not strings - and you're already parsing the strings into int values, but then ignoring the result. Why?

Comment: System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is "+ Integer.parseInt(sample) * Integer.parseInt(sample2)+ ".");

Comment: On a side note, do not catch exceptions and then issue a return statement. Just let the exception propagate.

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing that out, i should edit my title more stating that i wanted to convert string into integer and multiply them together. however why should i not issue a return statement? if i dont place the return statement the message appears together with the line which i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't multiply strings together. You can multiply *numbers*, and it sounds like that's what you want to do. Indeed, you're already parsing the strings as integers - and then ignoring the result. You just need to change this:

```
 Integer.parseInt(sample); 
 Integer.parseInt(sample2);
 System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is "+sample * sample2+ ".");
```

to:

```
 int value1 = Integer.parseInt(sample); 
 int value2 = Integer.parseInt(sample2);
 System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is "
     + (value1 * value2) + ".");
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i wanted! Just a question though, i believe you're not able to comment once i've marked the answer is that correct? Still quite new to stack overflow here.

Comment: @AdamW: No, I'm not aware of any timing-related comment restrictions like that.

Comment: ah okay, cause i did ask other questions and the moment i marked it as an answer the answers stopped coming in, not that i mind though as it was just further explanation as to why was it suppose to be that way instead. Anyway thank you once again for the answer! I'll mark this as the answer since it's the most precise one yet and earliest too!

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to multiply two string not two number

you should use like this :

`System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is "+ Integer.parseInt(sample) * Integer.parseInt(sample2)+ ".");`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, was kinda my mistake in terms of the title, should've typed multiply integer from string. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return value of Integer.parseInt() to variables. The variables passed as param stay unchanged.

```
 int a = Integer.parseInt(sample); 
 int b = Integer.parseInt(sample2);
 System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is " + a * b + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

1st suggestion: Don't (ever!) declare 2 methods that do exactly the same thing!!

```
public static String value() { //obtain *first and second* user input. 
  String sample = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert Value", "Enter amount ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
  if (sample.isEmpty()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!", "No Value Detected", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    sample = value();
  }
  return sample;
}
```

2nd suggestion: Don't check the validity of your input in both value() method and main():

```
public static int value() { //obtain second user input. 
  String sample = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert Value", "Enter amount ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
  if (sample.isEmpty()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!", "No Value Detected", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return value();
  }
  try {
    int v = Integer.parseInt(sample);
    return v;
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("System detects that you are using characters");
    return value();
  }
}
```

for this 2nd case, main becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x1 = value();
  int x2 = value(); // call again the *same* method

  System.out.println("The total multiplication that you have inserted is "+x1 * x2+ ".");
}
```

Comment: Hi there, could you further explain the `1st suggestion: Don't (ever!) declare 2 methods that do exactly the same thing!!` I don't quite understand why I shouldn't do that.

Comment: The idea behind methods is code re-usage: write it once and use it many times. So, let me return the question and ask you: why would you ever write the exact same method twice instead of calling the first one twice?